# How to implement range index alias in elasticsearch 2.X

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic has replaced the Range Filter with Range Query.  I am having trouble creating an index alias using a range and unfortunately there is not an example on the index alias page on how to do this.  I would like an alias "female_teen" to be all documents where gender = female and age = 13-19.

Here is what I am using to create my alias:  The range seems to be ignored.

```
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "people",
                 "alias" : "female_teen",
                 "filter" : { "term" : { "gender" : "female" } },
                 "query" : { "range" : { "age" : "[13 TO 19]" } }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```